# Cannot run C++ webservice (using libhttpserver) as systemd service, everything works correctly when running from terminal (as same user)

Tags: linux, debian, services, systemd, lxc

This is my systemd unit file (almost identical is used to run Meteor webservice and it simply works):

```
[Unit]
Description=SomeService

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/myapp/app
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myapp

[Install]
```

This is the systemd log (it is identical both when starting with system and also when restarting service manually):

```
● someservice.service - SomeService
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/someservice.service)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since sat 2017-03-04 14:54:29 CET; 1s ago
  Process: 1543 ExecStart=/opt/myapp/app (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 1543 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

mar 04 14:54:29 somehostname systemd[1]: Started SomeService.
mar 04 14:54:29 somehostname someservice[1543]: Unable to connect daemon to port: 3501
mar 04 14:54:29 somehostname someservice[1543]: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'httpserver::webserver_exception'
mar 04 14:54:29 somehostname someservice[1543]: what():  httpserver runtime error
mar 04 14:54:29 somehostname systemd[1]: someservice.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
mar 04 14:54:29 somehostname systemd[1]: Unit someservice.service entered failed state.
```

The port is surely unused, changing port or tricks like /bin/bash -c "sleep 5;/opt/myapp/app" or running as root (without User directive) doesn't help. I should also mention that I am trying to run it in systemd-nspawn container. Outside and inside container: up-to-date Debian Jessie (stable). Can someone help?

Comment: can you bump up the app's logging?  a debug log should give more information about the problem.  you say it works when started manually -- is that inside or outside the container?

Comment: Inside container. The program's debug log is inside posted systemd unit log.

Comment: This question is a variation of the FAQ [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239)